# LAST_TIME_CONTACTED has unexpected value

Tags: android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

When I try to get the last time that I contacted some contacts, the results has the value converted to "01/01/1970" but I know the real date and time of the last call (for example, it is 14/02/2016). I noted that in my logs the last saved call is that was at one and half year ago, but the call I try to find was in 2 years ago.

So, am I correct in understanding that after some long time the log loses the older calls and in the contacts2.db the last_time_contacted field updates to incorrect values?

Comment: Please note that the constant LAST_TIME_CONTACTED has been deprecated in October 2018, along with TIMES_CONTACTED. See the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns#LAST_TIME_CONTACTED) and [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider#ObsoleteData).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` is not somehow linked to the call log, it's just a timestamp value that is set on the contact.

`01/01/1970` means a value of 0 for that field, i.e. that contact never had its `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` value set, this can happen if that contact was recreated (re-synced, merged, split, etc.) since it was last contacted, erasing the previously set value.

Also note that `LAST_TIME_CONTACTED` can be updated not just by calls - sms, whatsapp, email apps, even social apps can and do update this value for a contact that was contacted via the app.

Answer (score 0):

LAST_TIME_CONTACTED has been deprecated and not updated from Android.Q and later.
[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns)